# I want to get a special curve in a picture

Tags: image-processing

I have a picture,and I want to get a special curve in this picture ,than draw the line in a new picture.inbut I can't do this .
Like this:
[image: example]

The picture is this 
[image]

Anybody have an idea?

Comment: This can be done with the method I describe in details [here][1]


  [1]: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44355/how-to-make-a-curve-selectable-from-a-scaned-image-and-convert-it-to-a-list-of-c/44358#44358

Comment: I'd say with [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29464/generating-an-average-curve-from-a-dense-set-of-semicontinuous-curves-which) together with the linked post from @AlexeiBoulbitch your question has an answer already

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A complete solution that gives essentially the result you want is the following:

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/coBQa.jpg"];

img = ImageResize[image, 300];(*scale down to speed up calculation*)
ImageAdjust[img, {4, 0.2}](*increase contrast*)
ColorReplace[%, White -> Black, 0.05](*"remove" the black text*)
MedianFilter[%, 5](*remove small speckles*)
EdgeDetect[%](*find edges*)
SetAlphaChannel[#, Binarize[#]] &[Colorize[MorphologicalComponents[%], 
ColorRules -> {2 -> Red, _ -> Black}]](*Make the right edge red and the rest transparent*)
ImageCompose[img, %](*compose the original image and the red line*)
```

To get it to work with the full size image you might need to play with the parameters.

Result:

[image]

Comment: +1, I've added the link, I hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Oh,thank you very much!!

Answer (score 7):

This method is mainly based on the `CurvatureFlowFilter` function, which can preserve the shape of the area according to the gradient of the graylevel.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/coBQa.jpg"] // ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"] &;
```

The threshold of the first `Binarize` can be determined by checking the graylevel of some sample points of the interested area:

```
imgBi = Binarize[img, {0.38, 0.48}]
```

[image: imgBi]

`CurvatureFlowFilter` is used here to smooth `imgBi` while keeping the edges relatively unchanged (Note: this function is very time-consuming):

```
imgSeg = CurvatureFlowFilter[imgBi, 10, 5]
```

[image: imgSeg]

`MorphologicalBinarize` is useful for excluding small irrelevant areas:

```
imgMorphBi = MorphologicalBinarize[imgSeg, {.4, .99}]
```

[image: imgMorphBi]

Use any edge extraction method to extract the edges:

```
imgEdges = GradientFilter[imgMorphBi, 1] // ImageAdjust // Binarize
```

[image: imgEdges]

```
HighlightImage[img, imgEdges]
```

[image: highlighted img]

Comment: nice to see use of CurvatureFlowFilter.

Comment: @s.s.o Thanks. It's a very good function, just a bit slow :(

Comment: A nice answer too.Thank you !!

Comment: @czp Glad to help :)