# Strategies to find curves on messy data using FindCurvePath

Tags: list-manipulation, signal-processing, cluster-analysis

I have a set of data points that correspond to roots of a transcendental equation with respect to a parameter (the abscissa) which, by the properties of the system, define continuous curves (might be open or closed). There are many roots and some are very close from one another. [Here is the actual data set.](http://pastebin.com/ywK30fTZ)

A `ListPlot` shows the data set and some of the branches can be seen:
[image: Roots of transcendental equation]

In order to extract some of the branches, I've used `FindCurvePath` to my `dataSet` in the following way:

```
tmpIdx = Sort[FindCurvePath[dataSet], Length[#1] > Length[#2] &];
ordCrv = Table[dataSet[[tmpIdx[[j]]]], {j, Length@tmpIdx}];
```

which is, at some measurement, very unsuccessful:
[image: Data after FindCurvePath]

Sorting `tmpIdx` has the purpose to put the largest sets of data at the front of it; then I can construct some of the curves `FindCuvePath` is able to find, eliminate those points from `dataSet` and try again. Of course this works, but it is a lot of hard, manual work and very time consuming, which I wouldn't mind if this were the only data set I had to process.

To help `FindCurvePath`, I've been applying it not only to `dataSet`, but also to `{f[#1], g[#2]} &@@@ dataSet`, where `f` and `g` are top of my head chosen (continuous) functions. Again, this works to some extent. The obvious problem is that it involves a lot of manual processing and is not only specific to the data set, but also to the branch in question.

I know there is no universal solution, and at some point manual intervention will be in order, but I was wondering if someone knows or has a better strategy to attack the problem.

Hope I made myself clear. Any comments or suggestions are very welcome.

**EDIT**

With some lack of judgement, I've just realized that I excluded some data from my analysis, which can be very useful to do the job. What I have is not a 2d list, but a 3d list. [Here it can be found.](http://pastebin.com/rfyCxcNK)

One can clearly see the separation between curves
[image]

[image]

Sorry for the omission, it's something I just realized.

**EDIT 2**

Maybe there is some way to relax the conditions on `FindCurvePath` so it looks for a piecewise linear curve? By taking a closer look to the smaller curves constructed by the function, it seems that its very unsuccessful whenever there are "return" points. I wish the function documentation were more complete.

Comment: Related: [(29294)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29294/121), [(29464)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29464/121)

Comment: This is one of those questions that's only hard to answer because there seems to be no documentation available about how `FindCurvePath` actually works. Can anyone give some idea of what the underlying algorithm is? The documentation is incredibly unhelpful.